# In scala shapeless library, is it possible to write a generic arity function when the arity > 22 (presumably using one of shapeless macros)?

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless, hlist, arity

The following code is a typical demo of one of shapeless' use case:

```
  def getHList[P <: Product, F, L <: HList](p: P)(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L]): L = {
    gen.to(p)
  }

    val v = getHList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

This gives the proper result, unfortunately, it relies on scala's tuple syntactic suger, and doesn't work when the number of argument > 22:

```
    val v = getHList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)

(this generates an error that looks this the follow)

[Error] /xxx/HListSuite.scala:41: 29 more arguments than can be applied to method getHList: (p: P)(implicit gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[P,L])L
one error found

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I wonder if there is a macro or another scala feature I can use to break this limitation, any advice?

I'm using scala 2.12.8 but can upgrade to 2.13 at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your goal is to generate an `HList` longer than 22 then there are plenty of ways

  ```
  type _23 = Succ[_22]
  val _23: _23 = new _23

  1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: 7 :: 8 :: 9 :: 10 :: 11 :: 12 :: 13 :: 14 :: 15 :: 16 :: 17 :: 18 :: 19 :: 20 :: 21 :: 22 :: 23 :: HNil
  import shapeless.syntax.std.traversable._
  import shapeless.ops.hlist.Fill
  (1 to 23).toHList[the.`Fill[_23, Int]`.Out]
  (1 to 23).toSizedHList(_23)
  implicitly[_1 *--* _23].apply //takes long
  ```

  Be careful, some of these calculations take long.
- Also you can define `Product23`, `Tuple23`

  ```
  getHList(Tuple23(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23))
  ```

  although syntax sugar just with brackets will not work. The name of case class isn't significant, it can be `MyClass` instead of `Tuple23`.
- In Dotty there is [TupleXXL](http://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/runtime/TupleXXL.html).
- If your goal is to write a method like `getHList` you can try to make it curried

  ```
  //libraryDependencies += "com.github.dmytromitin" %% "auxify-macros" % "0.6", scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-annotations" (in 2.13)
  import com.github.dmytromitin.auxify.macros.{aux, instance}

  def curriedGetHList[N <: Nat] = new PartiallyAppliedCurriedGetHList[N]

  class PartiallyAppliedCurriedGetHList[N <: Nat] {
    def apply[A](a: A)(implicit cghl: CurriedGetHList[N, A]): cghl.Out = cghl(a)
  }

  @aux @instance
  trait CurriedGetHList[N <: Nat, A] {
    type Out
    def apply(a: A): Out
  }
  object CurriedGetHList {
    implicit def mkCurriedGetHList[N <: Nat, A]
    (implicit
     helper: CurriedGetHListHelper[N, A, A :: HNil]
    ): Aux[N, A, helper.Out] = instance(a => helper(a :: HNil))
  }

  @aux @instance
  trait CurriedGetHListHelper[N <: Nat, A, L <: HList] {
    type Out
    def apply(acc: L): Out
  }
  object CurriedGetHListHelper {
    implicit def one[A, L <: HList]
    (implicit reverse: Reverse[L]): Aux[_1, A, L, reverse.Out] = instance(acc => reverse(acc))

    implicit def succ[N <: Nat, A, L <: HList]
    (implicit helper: Lazy[CurriedGetHListHelper[N, A, A :: L]]): Aux[Succ[N], A, L, A => helper.value.Out] =
      instance(acc => a => helper.value(a :: acc))
  }

  curriedGetHList[_10](1).apply(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)
  ```

  or

  ```
  def curriedGetHList[N <: Nat] = new HListBuilder[N, HNil](HNil)

  class HListBuilder[N <: Nat, L <: HList](l: L) {
    def apply[A](a: A)(implicit bhl: BuildHList[N, L, A]): bhl.Out = bhl(l, a)
  }

  @aux @instance
  trait BuildHList[N <: Nat, L <: HList, A] {
    type Out
    def apply(l: L, a: A): Out
  }
  trait LowPriorityBuildHList {
    implicit def succ[N <: Nat, L <: HList, A]: BuildHList.Aux[Succ[N], L, A, HListBuilder[N, A :: L]] =
      BuildHList.instance((l, a) => new HListBuilder(a :: l))
  }
  object BuildHList extends LowPriorityBuildHList {
    implicit def one[L <: HList, A](implicit reverse: Reverse[A :: L]): Aux[_1, L, A, reverse.Out] =
      instance((l, a) => (a :: l).reverse)
  }

  curriedGetHList[_23](1).apply(2).apply(3).apply(4).apply(5).apply(6).apply(7).apply(8).apply(9).apply(10)
    .apply(11).apply(12).apply(13).apply(14).apply(15).apply(16).apply(17).apply(18).apply(19).apply(20)
    .apply(21).apply(22).apply(23)
  ```
- Or you can divide long tuple into tuple of tuples and use deep `Generic` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858745/automatically-convert-a-case-class-to-an-extensible-record-in-shapeless) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710536/deriving-nested-shapeless-lenses-using-only-a-type/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923974/weird-behavior-trying-to-convert-case-classes-to-heterogeneous-lists-recursively) [4](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/deephlister.scala)).
- One more option is to write a whitebox macro

  ```
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

  def getHList(xs: Any*): HList = macro getHListImpl
  def getHListImpl(c: whitebox.Context)(xs: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    xs.foldRight[Tree](q"_root_.shapeless.HNil: _root_.shapeless.HNil")((h, t) => q"_root_.shapeless.::($h, $t)")
  }

  getHList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
  ```

  Since the macro is whitebox its return type will be proper, `Int :: Int :: ... :: HNil`.
- Maybe the easiest is to use `shapeless.ProductArgs`

  ```
  def getHList = new ProductArgs {
    def applyProduct[L <: HList](l: L): L = l
  }

  getHList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
  ```

  Actually `ProductArgs` are implemented in Shapeless via `scala.Dynamic` and whitebox macro.