# Scala Reflection issue on accessing case class attributes

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have been able to get a List of attributes for a case class using scala with Reflection.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def classAccessors[T: TypeTag]: List[MethodSymbol] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m 
}.toList

case class Z(a1: String, b1: String, id: Integer)
val z = classAccessors[Z]

val res1 = z.map(x => if(x.equals("value id")) "xxx" else x)
```

> However, the `.equals` does not work, but gives no error -> so I am
> missing something and I can't google it. Must be something basic.
>
> `.replace` does not work, how would that go?.
>
> How do I just get a normal List for processing? I note a `List[Object]`.
> Did not find anything either in that regard. Mmm.
> Can someone give an example of not using Reflection?

Comment: A method property is not an string.

Comment: Is this the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286557/getting-case-class-definition-which-points-to-another-case-class? It seems like you've just made some small progress on that and could edit that question rather than ask yet another one.

Comment: Well I actually solved it. I can't say it is easy. And not really findable. I added .map(_.toString()) @SilvioMayolo

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  So I have deduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` has type `MethodSymbol`. So `if(x.equals("value id")) "xxx" else x` has type `Any` (aka `Object`) because this is the minimal supertype of `String` and `MethodSymbol`.

And `x.equals("value id")` is always `false` because `MethodSymbol` and `String` are different types.

Try

```
val res1 = z.map(_.toString).map(x => if (x == "value id") "xxx" else x)
```

or

```
val res1 = z.map(_.name).map(x => if (x == "id") "xxx" else x)
```

Please notice that Java `.equals` is like Scala `==`, Java `==` is like Scala `eq`.

Answer (score 1):

This `val z = classAccessors[Z].map(_.toString())` solved it. Not sure about all the facts behind it, but List[Object] went to List[String].