# Generate Recursive Tree of Types of Case Class (with shapeless)

Tags: scala, shapeless

I would like to generate a tree of types starting from a given case class, **without instantiating a value**

Example:

```scala
case class C1(x: Int)
case class C2(s: String, b: Boolean
case class C3(c1: C1, c2: String)
```

Which forms a tree like this:

```
C3
|
+-- C1
|   |
|   +-- Int
|
+-- C2
    |
    +-- String
    |
    +-- Boolean
```

Approx. expected output, does not have to be JSON but a similar (ideally isomorphic) structure:

```json
{
  "_type": "C3"
  "c1": {
    "_type": "C1",
    "x": { "_type": "Int" }
  },
  "c2": {
    "_type": "C2",
    "s": { "_type": "String" },
    "b": { "_type": "Boolean" }
  }
}
```

It seems like `LabelledGeneric` is what I want, but I need to recursively traverse down somehow.  Also, `Typeable` seems to be able to generate a String representation of a type already.

Comment: For Scala 2 - Shapeless with LabelledGeneric, for Scala 3 - Mirrors, for Scala 2/3 without type-level programming with implicits for the simplest cases - Magnolia. Which part do you struggle with?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I tried the LabelledGeneric way, but struggled to get the recursive expansion working.

Comment: What are your attempts? Type class derivation is mostly about understanding how implicits works ("the prolog in your compiler", implicit priorities, what companion object does) and then recursion stop case -> recursion step -> conversion to/from Generic (basically induction with types). If induction is too unintuitive Magnolia is much easier, even if more constrained (would work for your case though).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286557/getting-case-class-definition-which-points-to-another-case-class