# Flattening a sealed case class hierarchy

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose I have a sealed case class hierarchy like the following:

```
sealed trait Expr
case class Const(val: Double) extends Expr
case class Plus(x: Expr, y: Expr) extends Expr
case class Times(x: Expr, y: Expr) extends Expr
```

- Is it possible to automatically convert expressions such as `Plus(1,Plus(2,3))` into a HList of HLists?
- Will the conversion work even inside some function `f(e: Expr)`, i.e. when the specific structure of e is not known at compile time?

Comment: `... when the specific structure of e is not known at compile time.` Since `Expr` is a `sealed trait`, then the compiler knows all sub-classes at compile-time, e.g. exhaustiveness matching. I don't understand this comment/question - can you please explain?

Comment: I mean: from inside f, it's not explicitly known if it's been called with f(Plus(1,x)) or f(Times(a,b)) -   Is that an obstacle to flattening the expression into a HList from inside f?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this has already been answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923974/weird-behavior-trying-to-convert-case-classes-to-heterogeneous-lists-recursively?rq=1) and that there's a corresponding [example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/deephlister.scala) in the Shapeless distribution as of shapeless-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.