# Another diverging implicit expansion

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

I have got 'diverging implicit expansion' error and can't find what is wrong.

There are some dummy classes to isolate the problem:

```
import shapeless._
type Field = String
trait Column[T]
trait Parameter
trait Row

implicit object IntColumn extends Column[Int]
implicit object DoubleColumn extends Column[Double]

trait Mapper[T] {
    def unmap(l: T): Seq[Parameter]
    def map(row: Row): T
 }

type MapperFactory[L] = (List[Field] => Mapper[L])
object Mapper {
  def apply[L](fields: List[Field] = Nil)(implicit mapper: MapperFactory[L]) = mapper(fields)
}
```

There is the code I expect to work or at least to compile:

```
trait LowPriorityMapperImplicits {
    implicit def fromMapper[H](implicit mapper: Mapper[H]): MapperFactory[H] = fields => mapper
}
object DivergingMapper extends LowPriorityMapperImplicits {
    implicit def caseMapper[L, H <: HList](implicit generic: Generic.Aux[L, H], mapper: MapperFactory[H]): MapperFactory[L] = ???
    implicit def hListMapper[H, T <: HList](implicit hMapper: MapperFactory[H], tMapper: MapperFactory[T]): MapperFactory[H :: T] = ???
    implicit def hNilMapper: MapperFactory[HNil] = ???
    implicit def singleMapper[H](implicit to: Column[H]): MapperFactory[H] = ???
}
```

And here are test cases:

```
trait F[X] {
    import DivergingMapper._
    //import LazyMapper._
    implicit protected val  xMapper: Mapper[X]

    // t1-t5 work
    val t0 = Mapper[A]()
    val t1 = Mapper[X]()
    val t2 = Mapper[A]()
    val t3 = Mapper[X]()
    val t4 = Mapper[(A, A)]()
    val t5 = Mapper[(X, А)]()

    // t6-t7 don't
    // diverging implicit expansion for type com.ardtrade.db.XMapper.MapperFactory[...]
    // starting with method caseMapper in object XMapper
    val t6 = Mapper[(A, X)]()
    val t7 = Mapper[(X, X)]()
}
```

I can't understand why `Mapper[(X, A)]` works, but `Mapper[(A, X)]` doesn't.

**Update:**

<strike>I tried to use `shapeless.Lazy` and it compiles, but I've got NPE getting value from lazy implicit.</strike>

Trying to answer Miles Sabin's request to post the version with Lazy which results in NPEs, I found out that my test case actually compiles and works with Lazy version:

```
object LazyMapper extends LowPriorityMapperImplicits {
    implicit def caseMapper[L, H <: HList](implicit generic: Generic.Aux[L, H],   mapper: MapperFactory[H]): MapperFactory[L] = ???
    implicit def hListMapper[H, T <: HList](implicit hMapper: MapperFactory[H], tMapper: Lazy[MapperFactory[T]]): MapperFactory[H :: T] = ???
    implicit def hNilMapper: MapperFactory[HNil] = ???
    implicit def singleMapper[H](implicit to: Column[H]): MapperFactory[H] = ???
}
```

I had NPEs due to the following implicit:

```
implicit def fromMapper[H](implicit mapper: Mapper[H]): MapperFactory[H] = fields => mapper
// every time we declare a new mapper as implicit val 
// and there is no way to create it properly 
// we get self initialization 
// with null without any compile error
implicit val nullMapper = Mapper[ABRACADABRA]()
```

It's my fault, but it is still not clear for me why we need Lazy at all, so the question still stands.

Comment: Could you post the version with `Lazy` the results in NPEs?

Comment: @MilesSabin I was wrong and updated the question. The version with lazy works perfectly, although I don't quite understand why we need it.

Comment: Your example is a bit elaborate to unravel, but it will be recursion appearing somewhere in the implicit resolution which `Lazy` is controlling. See my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27911353/146737).