# Why does scalac rise a "diverging implicit expansion" error here?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, shapeless

In the following code I try to derive typeclass instances with shapeless. However, in the case of a more complex case class (which is converted to a more complex HList), the compiler gives me a "diverging implicit expansion" even though it does not seem to resolve the same kind of implicit type twice. Maybe I am missing some other rule of the compiler?

(Fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WEpnAXN/0)

```
import shapeless._

trait TC[T]

sealed trait Trait1
case class SimpleClass(a: String) extends Trait1

sealed trait Trait2
case class ComplexClass(a: String, b: String) extends Trait2

object Serialization extends App {

    //Instances for HList
    implicit val hnilInstance: TC[HNil] = ???
    implicit def hconsInstance[H, T <: HList] (implicit t: TC[T]): TC[H :: T] = ???

    //Instances for CoProduct
    implicit val cnilInstance: TC[CNil] = ???
    implicit def cconsInstance[H, T <: Coproduct] (implicit h: TC[H], t: TC[T]): TC[H :+: T] = ???

    //Instances for Generic, relying on HNil & HCons
    implicit def genericInstance[T, H] (implicit g: Generic.Aux[T, H], t: TC[H]): TC[T] = ???

    the[TC[SimpleClass :+: CNil]]  //Works
    the[TC[Trait1]]                //Works
    the[TC[ComplexClass :+: CNil]] //Works
    the[TC[Trait2]]                //Fails with diverging implicit expansion
}
```

When trying to resolve `the[TC[Trait1]]` the compiler should do something like that:

```
TC[Trait1]
    Generic[Trait1]
    TC[SimpleClass :+: CNil]
        TC[SimpleClass]
            Generic[SimpleClass]
            TC[String :: HNil]
        TC[CNil]
```

which seems to work. However, with the 2-field case class, the compiler fails to do something like this - so I wonder: why do I have to use `Lazy` here already to make it work?

```
TC[Trait2]
    Generic[Trait2]
    TC[ComplexClass :+: CNil]
        TC[ComplexClass]
            Generic[ComplexClass]
            TC[String :: String :: HNil]
        TC[CNil]
```

I have created some fiddle so you can execute the code there directy.

Comment: I suspect Miles's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27911353/334519) is the explanation, although the case isn't exactly the same as mine in that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of years ago when I was working through [some issues like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25923974/334519) I found that the easiest way to figure out what the divergence checker was doing was just to throw some `println`s into the compiler and publish it locally. In 2.12 the relevant code is the `dominates` method [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Implicits.scala#L412), where we can replace the last line with something like this:

```
overlaps(dtor1, dted1) && (dtor1 =:= dted1 || {
  val dtorC = complexity(dtor1)
  val dtedC = complexity(dted1)
  val result = dtorC > dtedC

  println(if (result) "Dominates:" else "Does not dominate:")
  println(s"$dtor (complexity: $dtorC)")
  println(s"$dted (complexity: $dtedC)")
  println("===========================")
  result
})
```

Then we can `sbt publishLocal` scalac and try to compile your code:

```
Dominates:
TC[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]] (complexity: 7)
TC[shapeless.:+:[ComplexClass,shapeless.CNil]] (complexity: 6)
===========================
```

The problem here is that we're looking for a `TC` instance for `String :: String :: HNil` (the lowest node in your tree), but we have an open search for `ComplexClass :+: CNil` (three steps up). The compiler thinks that `String :: String :: HNil` both overlaps and dominates `ComplexClass :+: CNil`, and it bails out because that looks recursive.

This sounds ridiculous, so we can do an experiment to try to convince ourselves by adding some complexity to the coproduct part and seeing what happens. Let's just add a constructor:

```
case class Foo(i: Int) extends Trait2
```

Now everything works fine, and we get this message during compilation:

```
Does not dominate:
TC[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]] (complexity: 7)
TC[shapeless.:+:[ComplexClass,shapeless.:+:[Foo,shapeless.CNil]]] (complexity: 9)
```

So the `ComplexClass` hlist representation still *overlaps* the `Trait2` coproduct representation, but it doesn't dominate it, since the `Trait2` representation (the subject of the open implicit `TC` search we're worried about) is now more complex.

The checker is clearly being much too paranoid here, and its behavior [may change in the future](https://github.com/typelevel/scala/blob/typelevel-readme/notes/2.12.1.md#faster-compilation-of-inductive-implicits-pull5649-milessabin), but for now we're stuck with it. As you note, the most straightforward and fool-proof workaround is to stick a `Lazy` in there to hide the supposed recursion from the divergence checker.

In this case specifically, though, it looks like just putting the instances in the `TC` companion object works as well:

```
import shapeless._

sealed trait Trait1
case class SimpleClass(a: String) extends Trait1

sealed trait Trait2
case class ComplexClass(a: String, b: String) extends Trait2

trait TC[T]

object TC {
  //Instances for HList
  implicit def hnilInstance: TC[HNil] = ???
  implicit def hconsInstance[H, T <: HList](implicit t: TC[T]): TC[H :: T] = ???

  //Instances for CoProduct
  implicit def cnilInstance: TC[CNil] = ???
  implicit def cconsInstance[H, T <: Coproduct](implicit
    h: TC[H], t: TC[T]
  ): TC[H :+: T] = ???

  //Instances for Generic, relying on HNil & HCons
  implicit def genericInstance[T, H](implicit
    g: Generic.Aux[T, H], t: TC[H]
  ): TC[T] = ???
}
```

And then:

```
Does not dominate:
TC[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]] (complexity: 7)
TC[shapeless.:+:[ComplexClass,shapeless.CNil]] (complexity: 16)
```

Why does moving stuff around like this raise the complexity of the coproduct? I have no idea.

Comment: ticket on making these sorts of errors explain themselves more: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8467

Comment: I hadn't seen that issue, @SethTisue, but it sounds like it's only about restricting the output of `-Xlog-implicits`, and just having a more specific subset of the current messages isn't really going to help with weird divergence cases like this.

Comment: Very nice explaination! Even though we both seem to still not understand why the compiler is that paranoid, at least the point of failure is now very clear. Thank you!

Comment: @valenterry Yeah, unfortunately I think the _why_ is probably just "because this behavior is mostly unspecified and at some point the compiler developers decided mostly okay was good enough".